# Объединение двух гомогенных DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Пытаюсь решить такую задачу:

1. отобрать из исходного DataFrame некоторый набор строк,
2. присвоить в определенном столбце в выборке новое значение
3. **объединить обратно исходный DataFrame и обработанную
       выборку по совпадению индексов таким образом, чтобы в результате в
       исходном DataFrame сохранились изменения столбца, сделанные на шаге
       2.**

Споткнулся на шаге #3 - объединение.

Тестовый набор данных, обработанный в DataFrame:

```
test = {'UID' : ('00000639616', '00000675306', '00000675305','00000639617', '00000675301', '00000675302'),
          'ID': ('02ab9161', '02ab9162', '02ab9163','02ab9164', '02ab9165', '02ab9166 '),
        'АНДС': (True, True, True, False, True, False),
        'Дата': ('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01','2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'),
    'Бизнес-Линия': ('Сегмент1', 'Сегмент1', 'Сегмент1', 'Сегмент1', 'Сегмент1','Сегмент1')}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(test)
df_test.set_index(['IDКлиента', 'Агрессивный НДС', 'Дата инвестиции'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Выглядит DataFrame так:

```
                                                Расчет Бизнес-Линия
IDКлиента Агрессивный НДС Дата инвестиции
02ab9161  True            2019-01-01       00000639617     Сегмент1
02ab9162  True            2020-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9163  True            2021-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9164  False           2019-01-01       00000639617     Сегмент1
02ab9165  True            2020-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9166  False           2021-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
```

Шаги #1 и #2:

```
df_test1 = df_test.sample(2)
df_test1.loc[:, 'Бизнес-Линия'] = 'Сегмент 2'
```

Дают результат:

```
                                                Расчет Бизнес-Линия
IDКлиента Агрессивный НДС Дата инвестиции
02ab9165  True            2020-01-01       00000675306    Сегмент 2
02ab9162  True            2020-01-01       00000675306    Сегмент 2
```

На шаге #3 хочу получить новый DataFrame:

```
                                                Расчет Бизнес-Линия
IDКлиента Агрессивный НДС Дата инвестиции
02ab9161  True            2019-01-01       00000639617     Сегмент1
02ab9162  True            2020-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент 2
02ab9163  True            2021-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9164  False           2019-01-01       00000639617     Сегмент1
02ab9165  True            2020-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент 2
02ab9166  False           2021-01-01       00000675306     Сегмент1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще присвоить новое значение чем объединять два DF.

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [125]: df_test
Out[125]:
                                    UID Бизнес-Линия
ID        АНДС  Дата
02ab9161  True  2019-01-01  00000639616     Сегмент1
02ab9162  True  2020-01-01  00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9163  True  2021-01-01  00000675305     Сегмент1
02ab9164  False 2019-01-01  00000639617     Сегмент1
02ab9165  True  2020-01-01  00000675301     Сегмент1
02ab9166  False 2021-01-01  00000675302     Сегмент1
```

решение:

```
In [126]: mask = df_test1.index

In [127]: df_test.loc[mask, "Бизнес-Линия"] = "Сегмент 2"
```

результат:

```
In [128]: df_test
Out[128]:
                                    UID Бизнес-Линия
ID        АНДС  Дата
02ab9161  True  2019-01-01  00000639616     Сегмент1
02ab9162  True  2020-01-01  00000675306     Сегмент1
02ab9163  True  2021-01-01  00000675305    Сегмент 2
02ab9164  False 2019-01-01  00000639617     Сегмент1
02ab9165  True  2020-01-01  00000675301     Сегмент1
02ab9166  False 2021-01-01  00000675302    Сегмент 2
```

Comment: Вся беда в том, что присвоение значений происходит по отдельному сложноподчиненному рандомному механизму.